# How to create an edge in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, skphysicsbody

I am trying to create a single view game with borders covering the whole frame. My node will have to stay on screen and bounce back once it reaches any of the borders. I have used several instances but I think the issue must be from the iOS Simulator settings. I can't find out what it is though.

The code I have tried so far was:

```
self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody (edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
```

which stops my node from going off screen once it reaches the bottom or top of the screen. However, it still escapes once it reaches the left or right walls. The only way I was able to fix this was by creating separate invisible rectangles as such for the Est Wall for ex:

```
estWall.position = CGPointMake(725, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
estWall.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(1, CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame)))
estWall.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
self.addChild(estWall)
```

My node responds, however once I change the device to a different screen size iPhone, obviously the rect moves as such. What do I need to do to fix this? I don't want to use 725 as the estWall.position's x value cause it will be different on different devices.

Comment: What method contains these lines of code? It's possible you're creating the physics body before the frame of the view is set correctly.

Comment: Try adding `scene.size = skView.bounds.size` to your `GameViewController` before calling `skView.presentScene` and use your first codde

Comment: thank you. this fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is with the physics body for the whole screen is, but in the case of putting rectangles keeping them at the edge for every device is pretty simple. Use this:

```
estWall.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width + estWall.size.width/2, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
```

This will put it just outside the edge. For the other just do `0-estWall.size.width/2` for the x position. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with aligning sprites. Try heading over to your GameViewController.swift file and enter this below where it says 'scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill'.

```
scene.size = self.view.frame.size
```

You may also have to delete your GameScene.sks file but I'm not sure because I always delete mine anyways. Hopefully you don't, however.